# Extending div to full width of page when inside a container div

Tags: css

I have a centered webpage with fixed width that is being requested that the navbar and footer actually go the entire browser width. Thus breaking out of the container div. The page will never be a fixed height. Is this even possible? Code below. Codepen demo further below.

---

```
      <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
          Cu quando epicurei comprehensam pro, ne eam graeco oporteat. Cum at vitae dictas adipiscing, nisl vocent offendit nam ea. Has homero repudiandae no, cu ius nibh magna disputationi. Et sed esse gubergren percipitur. Eu qui vidit congue, at vix ludus mediocritatem, has ipsum persequeris reprehendunt at.


        </div>

        <div id="nav">Cu quando epicurei comprehensam pro, ne eam graeco oporteat. Cum at vitae dictas adipiscing, nisl vocent offendit nam ea. </div>

        <div id="body">
               Cu quando epicurei comprehensam pro, ne eam graeco oporteat. Cum at vitae dictas adipiscing, nisl vocent offendit nam ea. Has homero repudiandae no, cu ius nibh magna disputationi. Et sed esse gubergren percipitur. Eu qui vidit congue, at vix ludus mediocritatem, has ipsum persequeris reprehendunt at.

      Cum tempor probatus intellegat at, ut nisl consequat vis. Eum an mucius sadipscing. Ad eros sale vivendum quo, mei te nostrud instructior deterruisset. Iudico platonem eos ex, everti voluptatum in his. Ferri habeo blandit eam te. Doctus offendit praesent ius et, assum erroribus est cu.
           Cu quando epicurei comprehensam pro, ne eam graeco oporteat. Cum at vitae dictas adipiscing, nisl vocent offendit nam ea. Has homero repudiandae no, cu ius nibh magna disputationi. Et sed esse gubergren percipitur. Eu qui vidit congue, at vix ludus mediocritatem, has ipsum persequeris reprehendunt at.

      Cum tempor probatus intellegat at, ut nisl consequat vis. Eum an mucius sadipscing. Ad eros sale vivendum quo, mei te nostrud instructior deterruisset. Iudico platonem eos ex, everti voluptatum in his. Ferri habeo blandit eam te. Doctus offendit praesent ius et, assum erroribus est cu.
        </div>



        <div id="footer">
          Iudico platonem eos ex, everti voluptatum in his. Ferri habeo blandit eam te. Doctus offendit praesent ius et, assum erroribus est cu.

        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

---

```
      #content-wrapper { width:100%;  font-family:   Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

      #content { width:980px; margin:auto; }

      #header { background-color:tan; padding: 20px; margin-bottom:20px;}

      #nav {background-color:yellow; padding:20px;  margin-bottom:20px;}

      #body { background-color: green; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;}

      #footer { background-color:blue; color:white; padding:20px;}
```

---

http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/QwzPVa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, to do that just put your `header` and `footer` outside of `content` like so:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="nav"></nav>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="body"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Your header and footer should automatically be 100% width, but to ensure that you can assign a `width: 100%` to them just in case. And also set `margin: 0` on the `body` element to get rid of the spacing between your divs and viewport.

Comment: The nav doesn't have to be inside the header by the way, but it's usually nice to wrap both of those in something to separate them from the rest

Comment: Yes, but the content wrapper allows the header to be fixed width while still being centered on larger browser windows.

Comment: If you want the header to be fixed width, and centered, you can put both the header and the nav inside a wrapper (for example top-wrapper). Make sure the nav is not inside the header. Give top-wrapper and nav 100% width, and give header your desired width as well as margin: 0 auto; to center it

Comment: I feel I'm close, but I can't get my navbar to go 100% of browser window. Can you see anything wrong with this? Link here: http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/dPabKW

Comment: Just add a `body { margin: 0; }` to your css. The body element has margins by default